# how to print dict values based on key containing delimiters

Tags: python, dictionary

Actually i have a dict

```
x1={'b;0':'A1;B2;C3','b;1':'aa1;aa2;aa3','a;1': 'a1;a2;a3', 'a;0': 'A;B;C'}
```

Actually here my convention is `'a;0','b;0'` will contain tags and `'a;1','b;1'` will have corresponding values, based on this i have to group and print.
From this dict what output i want is

```
<a>       #this is group name
<A>a1</A> # this are tags n values
<B>a2</B>
<C>a3</C>
</a>
<b>
<A1>aa1</A1>
<B2>aa2</B2>
<C1>aa3</C1>
</b>
```

This is the sample dict which i given like this many groups may come like `c;0:.... d;0.....`

I am using code like
    a=[]
    b=[]
    c=[]
    d=[]
    e=[]
    for k,v in x1.iteritems(): 
      if k.split(";").count('0')==1: # i am using this bcoz a;0,b;0 contains tag so i am  checking if they contain zero split it.
        a=k.split(";") # this contains a=['a','0','b','0']
        b=v.split(";") # this contains 'a;0','b;0' values
      else:
        c=v.split(";") # this contains 'a;1','b;1' values
        for i in range(0,len(b)):
                        d=b[i]
                        e=c[i]
            print "<%s>%s<%s>"%(c,e,c)
Actually this code is working only 50% when single group is their in 
    dict('a;1': 'a1;a2;a3', 'a;0': 'A;B;C') and when multiple groups r their in 
    dict ('b;0':'A1;B2;C3','b;1':'aa1;aa2;aa3','a;1': 'a1;a2;a3', 'a;0': 'A;B;C') 
in both cases it prints
    
    **aa1
    aa2
    aa3**
    
its printing only recent value not all values

Comment: Huh...?  Please format the code.

Comment: maybe there is a better way to store your data.

Comment: @wim i am new to python, i think now its formatted i think. can u say me the code for this

Comment: @monkut.Their r many groups which i stored like this so i need code for this type. i can use if,else but if their r 100 groups i need add 100 if elif................... else conditions.

Comment: what error does it show?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware: dictionaries have no order. So the iteritems() loop does not necessarily start with 'b;0'. Try for example

```
for k,v in x1.iteritems():
    print k
```

to see. On my computer it gives

```
a;1
a;0
b;0
b;1
```

This gives a problem since your code assumes the keys to come in the order they appear in the definition of x1 [edit: or rather that they come in order]. You can e.g. iterate over sorted keys instead:

```
for k in sorted(x1.keys()):
    v = x1[k]
    print k, v
```

Then the problem with the order is solved. But I think you have more problems in your code.

Edit: Data structures:

it might be better to store your data in some way like

```
 x1 = {'a': [('A','a1'),('B','a2'),('C','a3')], 'b': ... }
```

if you cannot change the format, this is how you could convert your data:

```
x1f = {}
for k in x1.iterkeys():
    tag, id = k.split(';')
    if int(id) == 0:
        x1f[tag] = zip(x1[k].split(';'), x1[tag+';'+'1'].split(';'))
print x1f
```

From there it should be easier to convert to the desired output.

And depending if you want extend the complexity of the output in future,
you might want to consider using pyxml:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.Document()
```

then you can use the createElement and appendChild methods.

Comment: Thanks@Kyss Tao its printing in order,now i need that to be split and print in xml format which i posted with question

Comment: guys any one help me solving this pls.. its not printing all values.

Comment: please update your code, so it does not run into the problem I explained; make sure it is formatted; and append the error msg it produces, or the unexpected output you get